# How to get the size of the corner radius of widget in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, widgetkit, ipados

[image]
[image]

I want to maintain the same inset around my custom view. Exterior corner radius is required to change the corner radius of our custom views,

I could not find any environment variable or any other way to get the corner radius of the widget itself.

- **Just parsing a hardCoded value to `.cornerRadius()` is not work on every device. Since
  different devices may use a different radius for their widgets.**

```swift
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Hello")
                            .font(.title)
                        Text("Widget")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .cornerRadius(10)//<=here
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(5.0)
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have a much better way to do this in `iOS 14` using the `ContainerRelativeShape`.

`ContainerRelativeShape` is a new shape type that will take on the path of the nearest container shape specified by a parent with an appropriate corner radius based on the **position** of the shape.

In this instance, the system is defining the container shape for our widget, and we get the corner radius concentric with it super easy.

```
.background(ContainerRelativeShape().fill(Color.yellow))
```

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Hello")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Widget")
                }
                .padding()
                .background(ContainerRelativeShape().fill(Color.yellow)) //<=here
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(5.0)
    }
```